# How can i save the value in database with meteor?

Tags: meteor

In meteor framework inside pre-added code, the counter increases every time when it gets clicked. How to save the value using mongodb ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a collection on the server side to persist the data:

```
Meteor.isServer {
   Counter= new Mongo.Collection('Counter');
   // Server side method to be called from client
   Meteor.methods({
      'updateCounter': function (id) {
          if(typeof id && id) {
             return Counter.update({_id: id}, {$set: {counter: {$inc: 1}}});
          } else {
             return Counter.insert({counter: 1})
          }
       }
   })
   // Publication
   Meteor.publish("counter", function () {
      Counter.find();
   })
}
```

You can subscribe the data at the client:

```
Meteor.isClient{
   Template.yourTemplateName.created = function () {
      Meteor.subscribe('counter');
   }
   Template.yourTemplateName.heplers( function () {
      counter: function () {
          return Counter.findOne();
      }
   })
   Template.yourTemplateName.event( function () {
      'click #counterButtonIdName': function () {
          if(Counter.findOne()) {
              Meteor.call('updateCounter', Counter.findOne()._id);
          } else {
             Meteor.call('updateCounter', null);
          }
      }
   })
}
```

Html sample

```
<template name="yourTemplateName">
    <span>{{counter}}</span> //area where count is written
</template>
```

By this way you can achieve a secure server side processing of your data and the count will be persistent until you have data in the database. Also, this way you can learn Meteor's basics.

Answer (score 0):

Just `insert` it to a collection. Here's an `upsert` (i.e., update if exists, insert if not) function:

```
if (Saves.find({_id: Meteor.userId()})){
    Saves.update( {_id: Meteor.userId()}, {save: save} )
    console.log("Updated saves")
}
else {
     Saves.insert(save)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `autopublish` package exists, you can simply create a `Mongo.Collection` and insert this counter into the database:

```
var myCounter = 5;
var collection = new Mongo.Collection('collection');
collection.insert({counter: myCounter});
```

Hope this helps.